# How does defining rotate twice affects overall transformation?

Tags: javascript, animation

https://codepen.io/cassie-codes/pen/zWJxXj

This animation rotates N deg, translates, then rotate back?

What is happening?

```
@for $i from 1 through 18 {
  $a: #{$i*90};
  $b: #{$i*90+360};

  .blob:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    animation: move#{$i} 20s infinite linear;
  }

  @keyframes move#{$i} {
    from {
      transform: rotate(#{$a}deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-#{$a}deg);
    }
    to {
      transform: rotate(#{$b}deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-#{$b}deg);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In CSS rotations are not accumulative.

Comment: i dont get what that means,  if i understand the origin is 0,0, so a box would rotate with that axis, say 50 deg, then translate, then rotate back. but that's not what happens, as there would be no animation then because translate is same in from & to.

Comment: ok i think i got it

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out what is happening...

there are two things at play...

first the origin is top left.

any rotation would be relative to that axis.

when object is rotated, translation axis rotates with it, if object is flipped 90 deg left, and you translateX then it will move up and down, not horizontally.

which leads to second thing...

depending on angle, your translate is moving object on combo of X or Y axis

then if you rotate it back, the object will be in starting orientation but still translated according to angle... at 90deg right translation of 10px would be y: -10, x: 0.. and so on.. and rotating object back you'd get object that has been translatedY -10px;

end result is circular motion